# Implicit function theorem: am I using it correctly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

> Suppose that  $F\left ( x,y,u,v \right )$ and $G\left ( x,y,u,v \right )$ have continuous first partial derivatives. Suppose that  the equations $F\left ( x,y,u,v \right )=0$ and $G\left ( x,y,u,v \right )=0$ can be solved for $x, y$ as function of $u, v$.
>
> Express $\frac{\partial \left ( x,y \right ) }{\partial \left ( u,v \right ) } $ in terms of $\frac{\partial \left ( F,G \right ) }{\partial \left ( u,v \right ) } $ and $\frac{\partial \left ( F,G \right ) }{\partial \left ( x,y \right ) } $, where
> $$\tfrac{\partial \left ( x,y \right ) }{\partial \left ( u,v \right ) }=
> \begin{vmatrix}
>   x_{u} &x_{v} \\
>   y_{u} &y_{v}
> \end{vmatrix}, \qquad \tfrac{\partial \left ( F,G \right ) }{\partial \left ( u,v \right ) }=
> \begin{vmatrix}
>   F_{u} &F_{v} \\
>   G_{u}&G_{v}
> \end{vmatrix}, \qquad\tfrac{\partial \left ( F,G \right ) }{\partial \left ( x,y \right ) }=
> \begin{vmatrix}
>   F_{x} &F_{y} \\
>   G_{x}&G_{y}
> \end{vmatrix} $$  are Jacobian determiants.

Can I solve this problem in the following way?

Consider the function
$$H: \mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R^2, \qquad  \left ( x,y,u,v \right ) \mapsto (F\left ( x,y,u,v \right ),G\left ( x,y,u,v \right )  )$$

Since $x, y$ can be solved as function of $u, v$ - let's say
$$x=x(u,v),\space y=y(u,v),$$
I *guess* the implicit function theorem can be used here.

Then we have
$$DH=\begin{bmatrix}
  F_x&  F_y&  F_u& F_v\\
  G_x&  G_y&  G_u&G_v
\end{bmatrix},$$in which $$\begin{vmatrix}
  F_x&  F_y \\
  G_x&  G_y
\end{vmatrix}=\tfrac{\partial \left ( F,G \right ) }{\partial \left ( x,y \right ) }
\ne 0.$$

So, by the implicit function theorem
$$\begin{bmatrix}  x_u& x_v\\  y_u& y_v\end{bmatrix}=-\begin{bmatrix}  F_x& F_y\\  G_x&G_y\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \times \begin{bmatrix}  F_u& F_v\\  G_u&G_v\end{bmatrix}.$$

Finally, we have
$$\tfrac{\partial \left ( x,y \right ) }{\partial \left ( u,v \right ) }=-\left[\tfrac{\partial \left ( F,G \right ) }{\partial \left ( x,y \right ) }\right]^{-1}\space \times \space \tfrac{\partial \left ( F,G \right ) }{\partial \left ( u,v \right ) }.$$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: The problem is misleading. You are told that you can solve for $x,y$ in terms of $u,v$, but this can happen without having the hypotheses of the Implicit Function Theorem hold. If they do, then your solution is correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you sir. Sir could you give me some hint how I solve this problem without using IFT please?

Comment: You can’t. I’m just saying that this is a sloppy problem.

Comment: @TedShifrin Roger that, thank you sir!